# On click, show select, on select change show text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make something where you can dynamically insert an HTML block, and if you click on certain words a select box appears where you can select the item that you would like to replace the word. Once the item has been selected from the select list, the text value appears where the word used to be.

I'm just having trouble with the last part - ie. selecting the item and getting the text of that item to replace the select box.

```
var these_labels = "<select><option>Replacement A</option><option>Replacemnet B</option><option>Replacement C</option></select>";
$(".add").live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    $("#area").append("<div class='entry'>IF: <span class='label'>ANY</span></div>");
});

$(".label").live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    $(this).replaceWith(these_labels);
    $(this).change(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        $(this).replaceWith($(this).find(":selected").text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `this` throughout, however, once you replace the content, `this` is no longer appropriate. You'll need to keep references to the items your inserting so you can attach things to them specifically.

**Update:** Your updated code should be something like:

```js
$(".label").live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var labels = $(these_labels);
    $(this).replaceWith(labels);
    labels.change(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        // this one is fine because it is not being referenced later
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).find(":selected").text());
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I modify it so that I can replace the original text, with the selected value? Especially since there could be multiple entry classes. Maybe I'm not so hot with jQuery tonight lol

Comment: @MrJ Updated with code examples. As you see, you'll need to store a reference to the element created by `these_labels` and listen for the change on _that_ element. Also, you could use `$(this).val()` instead.

Comment: I think I understand now - thanks! Is there anyway of making the value the selected item if it were clicked again?